# I want to use the same form to store/update in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

I'd love to share the same form to store/update data on a Laravel AJAX form.
So I would change the form method depending of the action the user want to do.
i.e.
store method:

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('TechnicianController@store')}}" id="formTec">
    @csrf
```

update method:

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('TechnicianController@store')}}" id="formTec">
    @csrf @method('PUT');
```

I've an index page where I include the form that I open via Ajax

```
{{-- Form include  --}}
<div class="col-9" id="scheda" style="display:none">
  <form method="post" action="{{action('TechnicianController@store')}}" id="formTec">
    @csrf
  @include('technician.form')
</div>
```

Any idea how can I make I solve this problem?

Thank you

Valerio

Answer (score 0):

You could include the ID of the record you want to update and check to see if its there in your controller. If not, you can create a new record.

**UPDATED**

```
<div class="col-9" id="scheda" style="display:none">
      <form method="post" action="{{action('TechnicianController@store')}}" id="formTec">
          @csrf
          // only on update form
          <input type="hidden" name="technician_id" value="{{ $technician->id }}">
          @include('technician.form')
      </form>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
if ($request->input('technician_id'))
{
    // Update code
} else {
    // Create new code
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is what I was thinking: https://codepen.io/205media/pen/abOxXzB

Just to append the hidden input for the technician id when updating and not when creating a new record.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you for an example? I'm afraid I didn't understand very well

Comment: I'm afraid it won't feet on my structure. I'd better explain how my code is done. I've an index file that displays list of technicians, result of a foreach loop . Each <li> has inside an href that call a function to display the main form filled by datas. On the same index file I've a button that open another function that simply display the empty form.  So I dont understend how can I fit your suggestion in my code.

Comment: can you share more code so I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the index file I've a list of technicians that I show in this way

```
@foreach ($technicians as $technician)
              <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square text-muted"></i><a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();tecShow({{ $technician->id }})"><small class="text-muted"># {{$technician->id}}</small>  {{$technician->nome}} {{$technician->cognome}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
```

I also have a button to create a new tec

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();openTecForm()" href="" class="btn btn-outline-muted btn-sm text-secondary">
```

And a hidden div to show the form

```
<div class="col-9" id="scheda" style="display:none">
  <form method="post" action="{{action('TechnicianController@store')}}" id="formTec">
    @csrf
  @include('technician.form')
</div>
```

Inside my js file I've some functions:

**openForm()** -> reset the field, set up buttons and show the hidden div

**tecAdd()** -> perform the ajax call, store the content and append the result on the  ul in the index file

**tecShow(id)** -> fill the form data coming from the base

**tecEdit(id)** -> still working on it but it should update the record

Comment: Please have a look at UPDATE 2 on my original answer